# Should I prebook a train ticket when travelling within Switzerland?

Tags: trains, public-transport, bookings, switzerland

In the past I have found that there is no benefit to buying tickets in advance in Belgium, and I was wondering if the same was true of Switzerland.

Might I save some money buy buying in advance? It is a significant journey (Geneva to Interlaken via Bern), so I am hoping to keep costs down wherever possible.

Comment: I've found that return tickets for the journey I want are about CHF 171, but I know that, in the UK, if you buy on the day, the quoted price is not what you'll get. I just don't want to get stung by something like that due to my own inexperience!

Comment: Interesting! I was using SBB before, but I chose a Saturday in the future going from Geneva Airport. I expect this is related to peak times? A single for the route I found was ~CHF 86. It seems like return tickets don't save money either but, since my return is likely to be on a Friday, it may be worth buying singles on the day of my travel.

Comment: I once took a train from Bern, Switzerland to Graz, Austria.  The train cars were "carriage-style", with six seats to a compartment.  It was the most jam-packed, uncomfortable, and crowded train that I rode on while completing a four-month rail tour of Europe.  That being said, the views were spectacular.  I hope that domestic rail service is more comfortable.

Comment: Note: Until a couple of years ago Switzerland like Germany allowed you to buy tickets onboard the train in cash or with credit card, but not with debit card. Swiss rail changed this rule (supposedly to help the passenger). A few were unaware of the change and got fined for being on a train without a ticket despite having every intention of buying a ticket when onboard.

Comment: @pnuts It's slightly sneaky, it says "from CHF 35" because anybody can get a 50% discount. Regular fare is CHF 70.

Comment: @pnuts I might be wrong, see the answers. There is also a different kind of 50% discount I wasn't aware of and you can apparently combine both (so pay 25%?) Still, clicking through in your example reveals that the price really is CHF 70 in this case (at least without Halbtax Abo). Confusing…

Comment: @Relaxed why you deleted your answer?

Comment: @AliAwan I wasn't aware of the Super Saver fares, your answers covers that and is much more useful than mine (I upvoted it btw).

Comment: @Relaxed  i would have upvoted you answer for explaning that 35CHF is only availabe for half fare travel card,

Comment: @Mike you're right, buying a return ticket won't save you anything (in my experience as a local). I usually don't bother with them, and keep the flexibility instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Should I prebook a train ticket when travelling within Switzerland?

Yes, if you have a definite plan for a certain date and time. There are **super saver tickets** available for up to 50% discount but you have to buy those tickets in advance, preferably at least a week earlier. I have personally traveled to Switzerland twice and found this a lot cheaper than regular prices and Swiss pass. The only concern is super saver tickets are non refundable and if you miss  that train, it would cost you more to get another Swiss rail ticket.

Source: [Swiss Super Saver Ticket](http://www.sbb.ch/en/travelcards-and-tickets/tickets-for-switzerland/supersaver-tickets.html?cq_ck=1410520461221#faq)

And the price for your desired journey is around 36 CHF as a super saver ticket, but you have to buy them at least a week earlier. You may be able get a  super saver ticket on that particular day, which depends totally upon availability.

> **Note**: In the mobile app (which is otherwise quite decent) not all available super saver tickets are displayed (only the ones for the *quickest* routes). So on the online webpage you might see even cheaper options which aren't shown in the mobile app. Relevant news article (german): http://www.srf.ch/sendungen/kassensturz-espresso/sbb-sparbillette-im-internet-spart-man-mehr-als-mit-der-app

---

**Geneva to Interlaken**: As an example for next week, on the 12.01.2017 there's a ticket available for 36 CHF from Geneva to Interlaken.

---

[image]

Comment: "The only concern is super saver tickets are non refundable and if you miss that train, if would cost you more to get another Swiss rail ticket"  -- this is really useful information, thanks! I may not risk it on my outward journey, when I'm dependent on airlines, but my return journey is more controllable. It seems like booking is still a good idea based on @Relaxed's (now deleted) answer where they mentioned getting a seat.

Answer (score 5):

Get the SBB Mobile train app which offers discounts on trains if you book ahead.

Comment: (+1) Actually, it seems they are available online as well, great tip.